# How to make user data not visible for developer on firebabse

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This maybe very dumb question, but i'm making a note taking app, right now the data show on firebase look like this:
[image]

Mean that i (as developer) can see raw data, what user wrote, in this case header is "asadd" and the note

As an user, of course i will never use my app again if i know this, so my question is, how can i hide user data, i mean encrypt the data, so instead of "asadd" it will some some random string that only user know what is it
I worked with react-native, please help, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use [React Native AES](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-aes-crypto) package to encrypt data by using user's unique ID or password which only known by user and decrypt with the same. So that the data will be end to end encrypted.

Comment: So it work just by login to app, right? Right now i only use google login

Comment: you have to call that encrypt function and encrypt the data before sending data to firebase and also you have to decrypt data received so that user can read the notes. (Follow the usage described in the above library)